# How do I #include ActivityResultContracts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

When I try to do this:

```
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
```

Android Studio complains that "result" is undefined.

My build.gradle has this line in it:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

As far as I know, this should give me access to ActivityResultContracts.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I misinterpreted the information I was given. The implementation line in build.gradle needs to be this instead.

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-beta01'
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Getting a result from an activity documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), the Activity Result API was only introduced in Activity 1.2.0 and Fragment 1.3.0. AppCompat 1.2.0 only transitively depends on Fragment 1.1.0, which in turn only depends on Activity 1.0.0. This means you don't have a new enough version of Fragments and Activity to have access to the Activity Result APIs.

Therefore you can either upgrade your version of AppCompat (which *does* depend on the newer version of Fragment and Activity):

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

Or add an additional dependency specifically on Fragment (which pulls in the correct version of Activity):

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta01'
```